# Reading specific line of a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I am working on reading a file in php.
I need to read specific lines of the file.

I used this code:

```
fseek($file_handle,$start);
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{   
    ///Get and read the line of the file pointed at.
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $lineArray .= $line."LINE_SEPARATOR";

    processLine($lineArray, $linecount, $logger, $xmlReply);

    $counter++;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

However I realized that the `fseek()` takes the number of bytes and not the line number.

Does PHP have other function that bases its pointer in line numbers?

Or do I have to read the file from the start every time, and have a
counter until my desired line number is read?

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm, stepping over 500-1000 Kb file to get to the desired line seems inefficient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`SplFileObject::seek`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php)

```
$file = new SplFileObject('yourfile.txt');
$file->seek(123); // seek to line 124 (0-based)
```

Comment: thanks @JRL but does seek is based on bytes? and not line number?

Comment: Using splfileobject does not give the functionality fopen gives. Is there a easy way to turn this object in a fopen resource?

Answer (score 11):

Does this work for you?

```
$file = "name-of-my-file.txt";
$lines = file( $file ); 
echo $lines[67]; // echos line 68 (lines numbers start at 0 (replace 68 with whatever))
```

You would obviously need to check the lines exists before printing though.  Any good?

Comment: thanks @vivid-colours but because I am reading a large file, like logfiles :( i need to read the first 100 then the next only onScroll..so although I know which line to read from next im looking at how to read directly to the line..

Answer (score 5):

You could do like:

```
$lines = file($filename); //file in to an array
echo $lines[1];           //line 2
```

OR

```
$line = 0;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

while (($buffer = fgets($fh)) !== FALSE) {
   if ($line == 1) {
       // $buffer is the second line.
       break;
   }   
   $line++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must read from the beginning. But if the file never/rarely changes, you could cache the line offsets somewhere else, perhaps in another file.

Comment: what do you mean cache the offsets? when i call the file reading again i can go directly to the remaining lines that i need to read? @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,the simplest one

```
$buffer=explode("\n",file_get_contents("filename"));//Split data to array for each "\n"
```

Now the buffer is an array and each array index contain each lines;
To get the 5th line

```
echo $buffer[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use function `file($filename)` . This function reads data from the file into array.