# Read File to specific line php

Tags: php, fgets

I'm trying to read a large file (about 5 million lines), it keeps reaching memory limit. Is there a way i can read the file to a particular line, then increment a counter and continue from the next line?

Here is the code i'm working with, how do i add a pointer to a starting line for the fgets?

```
$handle = @fopen("large_file.txt", "r");
if($handle){
   while(($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false){
      //get the content of the line
    }
}
```

I'm not trying to read just one particular line, i'm trying to read from say line 1 to  line 10,000, then start again from line 10,001 to another  10,000 lines, like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this function you should use iteration and get line by range.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('yourfile.txt');

echo getLineRange(1,10000);

function getLineRange($start,$end){
   $tmp = "";

   for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    $tmp .= $file->seek($i);
   }
   return($tmp);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post 2 answers (rather, edit your original answer).

Answer (score 0):

i think answer would be here [Reading specific line of a file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374093/reading-specific-line-of-a-file-in-php)

you can use seek to get specific line location

```
$file = new SplFileObject('yourfile.txt');
$file->seek(123); // seek to line 124 (0-based)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to read just one particular line, i'm trying to read from say line one to  line 10,000, then start again from line 10,001 to another  10,000 lines, like that.

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing a large file in chunks can be done in PHP using `fseek()`/`ftell()` and saving the context between chunks. (`SplFileObject::seek()` can seek directly by line but seems to have [performance issues with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877447/delete-first-x-lines-from-a-file-php).)

Assuming you have some sort of batch processor available, the following sample should give you an idea of the method. It is untested but derived from code in production.

```
<?php

$context = array(
    'path' => 'path/to/file',
    'limit' => 1000,
    'line' => NULL,
    'position' => NULL,
    'size' => NULL,
    'percentage' => 0,
    'complete' => FALSE,
    'error' => FALSE,
    'message' => NULL,
);

function do_chunk($context) {
    $handle = fopen($context['path'], 'r');
    if (!$handle) {
        $context['error'] = TRUE;
        $context['message'] = 'Cannot open file for reading: ' . $context['path'];
        return;
    }
    // One-time initialization of file parameters.
    if (!isset($context['size'])) {
        $fstat = fstat($handle);
        $context['size'] = $fstat['size'];
        $context['position'] = 0;
        $context['line'] = 0;
    }
    // Seek to position for current chunk.
    $ret = fseek($handle, $context['position']);
    if ($ret === -1) {
        $context['error'] = TRUE;
        $context['message'] = 'Cannot seek to ' . $context['position'];
        fclose($handle);
        return;
    }

    $k = 1;
    do {
        $context['line']++;
        $raw_line = fgets($handle);
        if ($raw_line) {
            // Strip newline.
            $line = rtrim($raw_line);
            // Code to process line here.
            list($error, $message) = my_process_line($context, $line);
            if ($error) {
                $context['error'] = TRUE;
                $context['message'] = $message;
                fclose($handle);
                return;
            }
        } elseif (($raw_line === FALSE) && !feof($handle)) {
            $context['error'] = TRUE;
            $context['message'] = 'Unexpected error reading ' . $context['path'];
            fclose($handle);
            return;
        }
    }
    while ($k++ < $context['limit'] && $raw_line);

    // Save position of next chunk.
    $position = ftell($handle);
    if ($position !== FALSE) {
        $context['position'] = $position;
    } else {
        $context['error'] = TRUE;
        $context['message'] = 'Cannot retrieve file pointer in ' . $context['path'];
        fclose($handle);
        return;
    }

    if (!$raw_line) {
        $context['complete'] = TRUE;
        $context['percentage'] = 1;
    } else {
        $context['percentage'] = $context['position'] / $context['size'];
    }

    fclose($handle);
}


// Batch driver for testing only - use a batch processor in production.
while ($context['complete']) {
    do_batch($context);
}
if ($context['error']) {
    print 'error: ' . $context['message'];
} else {
    print 'complete';
}
```